# Creating Bat file to execute a command on all files in folder

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file

How to create a bat file that will execute a single command on all files with a particular extension.

I look for something like this which is there is linux for windows batch files

command *.extension

or even a way to loop through the file with extension would do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your command changes the filename and uses the same extension then this solution has a bug, and some files are processed more than once.  There are ways around that.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.ext) do (
echo "%%a"
)
```

Comment: @foxdrive what does %%a mean. Can you please explain

Comment: The for in do command uses a metavariable and I called it %%a.  In the example above, each file that matches the *.ext filespec will be echoed in place of the %%a inside the double quotes.    You could also use %%b and %%c and %%A and %%B and %%C etc and they are case sensitive.  In other types of for in do loops you assign say %%a and then extra tokens are used in alphabetical ASCII order, which is why I use %%a and not %%? or %%# which you see some people using.  When every file has been echo'ed then the loop above will finish.

Comment: thanks a lot. Its extremely difficult to understand when the linux pattern and windows pattern is so different